# vuex unknown action type: RawHTML in a VueJS using typescript application

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am getting a '[vuex] unknown action type: RawHTML' when trying to dispatch an action on a component.
Those errors are usually caused by not correctly namespaced modules, but I am not using modules here.

store/index.ts

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import Vuex from 'vuex'
    Vue.use(Vuex)
    const SETRAWHTML = ''

    const store =  new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
       raw:''
       },
    mutations: {
    [SETRAWHTML](state,str){
     state.raw=str
    },
    },
    actions: {
    RawHtml({commit}, str) {
      commit(SETRAWHTML, str)
    },
    },
    getters: {
    getRawHTML (state) {
      return state.raw
    }
    },
   })

    export default store;
```

main.ts

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import App from './App.vue'
    import router from './router'
    import store from './store'

    Vue.config.productionTip = false

    new Vue({
        router,
        store,
    render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app')
```

my component

```
    click(){
    store.dispatch('RawHTML', this.rawHTML)
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of `actions` is case-sensitive and you should dispatch the action with the same name as it's defined in the store, `RawHTML` and `RawHtml` don't refer to the same action, so you should respect the case and write the action dispatch as follows :

```
click(){
    store.dispatch('RawHtml', this.rawHTML)
}
```

Comment: I don't know how I midded that honestly lol. Thank you!